# Does Spring Security includes token based authentication

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to implement token based authentication, I'm using Spring Boot... I wanted to ask if Spring Security includes token based authentication?

Comment: I don't think Spring itself has special components for JWT based security. However there are few guides on the net and it would be worth checking how jHipster does it - https://www.jhipster.tech/security/#jwt .

Comment: Yeah - nothing special in jHipster: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/security/jwt/JWTFilter.java.ejs . Pretty much the same you get from following this tutorial - https://medium.com/omarelgabrys-blog/microservices-with-spring-boot-authentication-with-jwt-part-3-fafc9d7187e8

Comment: Is basic auth not a token based authentication scheme? @PavelHoral

Comment: Nope... that i username/password based authentication. BASIC auth is supported by Spring Security out of the box.

Comment: So if I need to implement Token Based Auth, JWT comes to play ? To be direct, Does Spring Security supports token based authentication?